# Comparing string and OffsetDateTime in JPA / postgresQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am migrating a codebase from mysql to postgresQL.

I have an entity

```
public class FooEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = DateTimeConverter.class)
private OffsetDateTime fooDate;
```

The entity is stored in a foo table with fooDate as a VARCHAR. the DateTimeConverter make the conversion between string / offsetDateTime.

I have a SQL request doing :

```
        @Query("""SELECT f.id as id,
        f.fooDate as fooDate,
        FROM FooEntity f
        WHERE (:fooDate IS NULL OR f.fooDate >= :fooDate)""")
Page<Map<String, Object>> findAllByFooDate(Pageable pageable, OffSetDateTime fooDate);
```

My first issue was that if mysql have no issue with fooDate parameter being an OffsetDateTime, postgresQL will complain that the parameter is an unknown type.

First solution was to convert OffsetDateTime to a String in the method signature. works well for postgresQL, but now I have an hibernate issue that complain that f.fooDate >= :fooDate are not the same type.

How can I handle properly that issue ?

Comment: "*with fooDate as a VARCHAR*" - Why, oh Why? **Never**, ever store timestamp values in `varchar` columns. The column should be defined as `timestamptz` in the database. You aren't using `String` in Java either, so why use the wrong data type in the database?

Comment: Because a database is not capable of handling offset correctly, timestamptz only store utc value

Comment: Yes, and `timestamptz` will be converted to the local time zone of the database client. But if you don't want an automatic conversion. Use a `timestamp` column and store the "original" time zone in a second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hibernate 6 you can use `cast(f.fooDate as LocalDateTime)` or `cast(f.fooDate as Timestamp)` to convert a string representation of a datetime to a timestamp. This *should* work if the database understands the string representation that you have used to encode the offset datetime.

(You might also try `cast(f.fooDate as OffsetDateTime)`, though this doesn't really work especially well on MySQL or PostgreSQL.)

On the other hand, it will *not* work if your `AttributeConverter` encodes the offset datetime to some format you invented that the database doesn't understand.

In that case, you would need to:

1. figure out a SQL expression that parses your offset data time format, perhaps by writing a SQL function and exporting it to the database, and
2. register that as a custom HQL function using a `FunctionContributor`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually use cast(f.fooDate as String) > :fromDate , since we store it in standard ISO format, the string cast works properly.

Comment: But that doesn't seem like it would correctly order date times in different time zones.